# How to determine the maximal interval for a solution with a square root?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to understand the example below. What I don't understand is the last paragraph. Why is that the term under the square root is not allowed to be zero?

[image: to]

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed to be zero so it can be differentiated. Think (or calculate) what the derivative of $x(t)$ would look like, its domain and where it is continuous (the book is saying, so that the solution is class $C^1$).
For that particular excerxise is all that you need to know. Later on ODE and IVP exercises you can discuss if you admit  solutions and its derivatives with different domains, such as [a,b) and (a,b) respectively, just to satisfy initial conditions at a.

Comment: I still don't get it. Why would $x(t)$ not be of class $C^1$ if the term under the root is zero?

Comment: Maybe the fourth-root is misleading, but think about any other even-index root (like $\sqrt{x}$ for example). They are all defined at $x=0$ but not differentiable at $x=0$. So, those derivatives are continuous in the interval $x>0$, hence, the function is class $C^1$ in $(0,+\infty)$, even though the function is defined at $x=0$.  In ODE's, we try to always find solutions that are continuously differentiable, they must meet some regularity requirements to define a derivative at the first place.